# Arranging multiple layers of images into circles? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

[image: diagram]

I'm looking for some guidance on how to achieve the effect that has been pictured. So I'm learning about JS and jQuery and I want to build a circle that is essentially, made of circles. Is this possible? Any information will be helpful. I know you can arrange divs/images around a circle, but what about multiple layers? [circles within circles, essentially?}

Comment: This doesn't sound too difficult for an initial implementation.  You can create n # of "circle" div's, set their position to absolute, and move them around (adjust css top/left) via JS or JQ.  The trickiest part is probably figuring out how to avoid individual circles from overlapping (unless you want that) ie. if you were placing them at random based on some radius.

Comment: The "MeasureIt" plugin for Firefox will save you a lot of cut-and-try when you're positioning the individual images.  Also, you can position items `absolute` inside a `<div>` that's positioned relative or absolute, which will allow you to move the whole circle-of-circles around on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this before noticing you wanted circles in the center, too, and not just around the perimeter, but here it is anyway:

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/gowame/1/edit?js,output)

**Javascript**

```
var app = {
  count : 15,
  el : {
    self : document.getElementById('wrap'),
    width : document.getElementById('wrap').clientWidth,
    height: document.getElementById('wrap').clientHeight 
  },
  circle : {
    radius : ( document.getElementById('wrap').clientWidth / 2 ) - 50,
    centerX : ( document.getElementById('wrap').clientWidth / 2 ),
    centerY : ( document.getElementById('wrap').clientHeight / 2 ),
  },
  methods : {
    circle : function(radius, steps, centerX, centerY) {
      var xValues = [centerX];
      var yValues = [centerY];
      for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
          xValues[i] = (centerX + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / steps));
          yValues[i] = (centerY + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / steps));
      }

      return [xValues, yValues];
    }
  }
}


var coords = app.methods.circle(app.circle.radius, app.count, app.circle.centerX, app.circle.centerY);

for ( var i=0; i<app.count; i++ ) {
  var x = coords[0][i],
      y = coords[1][i];

  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * app.count) + 1);

  var div = document.createElement('div')
      div.style.left = (x-25) + 'px'
      div.style.top = (y-25) + 'px'
      div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/med/men/'+rand+'.jpg")'

  app.el.self.appendChild(div)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is not trivial. Not about JS/JQuery, but it is all about math!

There's a whole math study about circle packing. Please check this out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

You won't find easily places where you can find ready algorithms for this. But I would start with hexagonal packing algorithms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) and then inscribe circles in it.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely something I was looking for :)